# Pickling a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, canopy

I am trying to pickle a DataFrame with

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
data = pd.read_table('Purchases.tsv',index_col='coreuserid')
data.to_pickle('Purchases.pkl')
```

I have been running on "data" for a while and have had no issues so I know it is not a data corruption issue. I am thinking likely syntax but I have tried a number of variants. I hesitate to give the whole error message but it ends with:

```
\pickle.pyc in to_pickle(obj, path)
 13     """
 14     with open(path, 'wb') as f:
 15         pkl.dump(obj, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

 SystemError: error return without exception set
```

The Purchases.pkl file is created but if I call

```
data = pd.read_pickle('Purchases.pkl')
```

I get EOFError. I am using Canopy 1.4 so pandas 0.13.1 which should be recent enough to have this functionality.

Comment: how large is the dataframe? See other reports here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3699

Comment: Moderate: data.shape = (21324932, 7)

Comment: It looks like a known bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue11564

Comment: Have you tried an hdf5 type method- might have more luck with such a large dataframe if it is mainly numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast forward a few years, and now it works fine. Thanks pandas ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a class from your DataFrame and pickle it after.

This can help you:
[Pass pandas dataframe into class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949755/pass-pandas-dataframe-into-class)